# Filter List Connecting HP Quality Center using Java

Tags: java, hp-quality-center

I want a list which has the names of all the filters available to provide in filter list for fetching the defect list from the HP Quality Center.

Here is my code:

```
    Com4jObject coBugFactory = connection.bugFactory();
    IBugFactory bugFactory = coBugFactory.queryInterface(IBugFactory.class);

    Com4jObject coFilter = bugFactory.filter();
    ITDFilter filter = coFilter.queryInterface(ITDFilter.class);
    filter.filter("BG_STATUS", "Not Cancelled");
    filter.filter("BG_DETECTED_IN_REL", "XYZ UYR");
```

Which all fields can I use in filer here ?

Answer (score 0):

`TDFilter` objects have a `Fields` property, which is a list of fields for the TDFilter's parent object—all of them can be used to filter for objects. From the OTA API Reference (VB):

```
Public Property Fields() As List
```

Result for a filter from `BugFactory`:

BG_ACTUAL_FIX_TIME BG_RESPONSIBLE BG_ATTACHMENT BG_CLOSING_VERSION BG_CLOSING_DATE BG_DEV_COMMENTS BG_CYCLE_ID BG_BUG_ID BG_DESCRIPTION BG_DETECTED_BY BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC
BG_DETECTED_IN_REL BG_DETECTION_VERSION BG_DETECTION_DATE BG_ESTIMATED_FIX_TIME BG_EXTENDED_REFERENCE BG_HAS_CHANGE BG_VTS BG_PLANNED_CLOSING_VER BG_REQUEST_ID BG_REQUEST_NOTE BG_REQUEST_TYPE BG_REQUEST_SERVER BG_PRIORITY BG_PROJECT BG_REPRODUCIBLE BG_RUN_REFERENCE BG_SEVERITY BG_STATUS BG_STEP_REFERENCE BG_SUBJECT BG_SUMMARY BG_TARGET_RCYC BG_TARGET_REL BG_TEST_REFERENCE BG_CYCLE_REFERENCE BG_TO_MAIL BG_BUG_VER_STAMP BG_USER_01 BG_USER_02 BG_USER_03 BG_USER_04 BG_USER_10 BG_USER_05 BG_USER_06 BG_USER_11 BG_USER_07 BG_USER_12 BG_USER_08 BG_USER_13 BG_USER_09 BG_USER_14
BG_USER_20 BG_USER_15 BG_USER_16 BG_USER_21 BG_USER_17 BG_USER_22 BG_USER_18 BG_USER_23 BG_USER_24 BG_USER_19 BG_USER_HR_01 BG_USER_HR_02 BG_USER_HR_03 BG_USER_HR_04 BG_USER_HR_05 BG_USER_HR_06

Another way to get the possible fields is to consult the HP ALM Database Reference which lists all fields.